# Detect where a Mixin is included

Tags: css, sass, mixins

Is there a way to determine where a mixin has been included? IE:

**Includes**

```
@include test();

.test {
    @include test();
}
```

**MIXIN**

```
@mixin test(){
    @if (weAreNested) {
        // We are in a css selector
        &.test {}
    } @else {
        // we are not inside any selector
        .test {}
    }
}
```

So, is there some sort of directive that we can use to do this?

Using the & before a selector already knows if we are at the base level or not and will not compile the css files, so I was wondering if there is a way that they let us test this?

Cheers

Comment: Are you using the original Ruby Sass compiler, or one of the many implementations that have been written for other languages?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is technically possible, but I'm pretty sure it's not a good idea.

If you think of mixins as like functions in any programming language, your question can be rephrased as "can a function determine where it was called from in order to trigger different functionality". While this is indeed possible in many languages - by processing the current "stack trace", for instance - using it for anything other than debugging would certainly lead to hard-to-maintain code.

More specifically, your example shows a single mixin performing two rather different jobs:

- the `weAreNested` branch adds some rules to a particular ruleset, as long as the element being matched also has an additional class
- the `else` branch creates a global rule for all elements matching a particular class; in fact, this example doesn't gain anything by being a mixin, although an example with parameters would be possible

It seems to me to be a far better idea to:

- *either* have two mixins, named appropriately, and perhaps even sharing implementation via a third mixin
- *or* use a parameter to the mixin to explicitly state which behaviour you want, rather than having it "magically" inferred from the context in which the mixin is called

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this was valid at the time this question was asked (back in 2014) but at least in `lib-sass` 3.5.5  (which I'm currently using, still old) you could simply look at `&` and see if it was null or not.

**Example:** So in your case, we just check `& != null` and then we know we can use it, i.e.:

```
@mixin test(){
    @if (& != null) {
        // We are in a css selector
        &.test {}
    } @else {
        // we are not inside any selector
        .test {}
    }
}
```